# How to return a C-String from a function and display it

Tags: c++, string, c-strings, strcmp

I can't get my program to display the whole c-string, it only displays the first letter! I am trying to write a function that asks the user to input 2 c-strings. I then have a separate function to determine which c-sting is greater alphabetically, and another to display. Every time it displays the c-strings it only displays the first letter though. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I need it to display the whole c-string.

Here is the function that asks the user for two c-strings:

```
const char *getData(char *c, char *d)
{
    cout << "Enter the first c-string: ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(c, 50);
    cout << "Enter the second c-string: ";
    cin.getline(d, 50);
    return c, d;
}
```

Here is the function that compares the c-strings

```
const char findBigger(char *c, char *d)
{
    if (strcmp(c, d) == 0)
        return *c;
    else if (strcmp(c, d) < 0)
        return *c;
    else if (strcmp(c, d) > 0)
        return *d;
}
```

And here is the function that displays the inputs and the greater c-string

```
void displayBigger(const char *c, const char *d, const char *maxChar)
{
    cout << "The first c-string is " << c << endl;
    cout << "The second char is " << d << endl;
    cout << "The bigger value is " << maxChar << endl;
    cout << "__________________________________________" << endl;
}
```

In `main()` I have

```
char first[50],
second[50]'
maxArray[50];
getData(first, second);
*maxArray = findBigger(first, second);
displayBigger(*first, *second, *maxArray);
```

The output of the program is:

```
Enter the first c-string: apple pie
Enter the second c-string: peach pie
The first char is a
The second char is p
The bigger value is a
__________________________________________
```

How do I get it to print the whole c-string? It should display "apple pie" and "peach pie"

Comment: `*maxArray=` doesn't do what you think it does. It doesn't copy an entire array to another one. If you tried to actually use C++ `std::string`s, none of this would be necessary. To actually do what you want to do, simply replace all the spawning grounds for buffer overflows and memory corruption, a.k.a. "arrays" with `std::string`s, and adjust the code accordingly.

Comment: `return c, d;` -- This does not do what you think it does.

Comment: In `findBigger`, you are calling `strcmp` with the same parameters 3 separate times.  All you need is one call and just save the return value.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I wish I could use ```std::string``` but my teacher does not want us to use it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ok so it looks like I made a mistake by using ```return c, d;``` I can't figure out how to properly return the c-strings from the function. There is nothing about it my textbook and the tips I found online don't seem to do the trick.

Comment: *but my teacher does not want us to use it* -- Well, this is another `C` class masquerading as a C++ class.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie my school is so backwards. They won't even let us use vectors.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie can you please explain what ```return c, d;``` does in my code? Maybe if I know what it does I find the correct way to return the c-strings

Comment: The `return c, d;` returns `d`.  It is too involved to get into as to why that it is (has to do with the comma operator).  There is no need to return anything, and just declare the `getData` function as returning `void`, not `const char *`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several issues with your code, not withstanding the obvious one of not using `std::string`.

**Issue 1:**

```
const char findBigger(char *c, char *d)
{
    if (strcmp(c, d) == 0)
        return *c;
    else if (strcmp(c, d) < 0)
        return *c;
    else if (strcmp(c, d) > 0)
        return *d;
}
```

1. This function should return `const char *`, not `const char`.
2. You are needlessly calling `strcmp` 3 times with the same set of arguments.  All you need is to call `strcmp` once and test that value:

The fixed code could look like this:

```
const char* findBigger(const char *c, const char *d)
{
    if ( strcmp(c, d) <= 0 )
        return c;
    return d;
}
```

Note that the arguments are `const char *`, since you are not changing the data contained within the C-strings.

---

**Issue 2:**

```
char first[50],
second[50]'
maxArray[50];
getData(first, second);
*maxArray = findBigger(first, second);
displayBigger(*first, *second, *maxArray);
```

1. The calling function (assuming it is `main`) declared `maxArray` as an array of `char`, but should have been declared as a `const char *`.
2. The call to `displayBigger` should have pointers passed to it.

Here is the fixed version:

```
int main()
{
    char first[50],
    second[50];
    
    getData(first, second);
    const char *maxArray = findBigger(first, second);
    displayBigger(first, second, maxArray);
}
```

---

**Issue 3:**

```
const char *getData(char *c, char *d)
{
    cout << "Enter the first c-string: ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(c, 50);
    cout << "Enter the second c-string: ";
    cin.getline(d, 50);
    return c, d;
}
```

The `getData` does not need to return `const char *`, since the arguments are pointers to `char` buffers that will be filled in.  Then this line:

`return c, d;`

does not return two values, only `d` due to the comma operator.  This becomes a moot point, since it is not necessary once the function is declared as `void`.

The fixed version:

```
void getData(char *c, char *d)
{
    cout << "Enter the first c-string: ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(c, 50);
    cout << "Enter the second c-string: ";
    cin.getline(d, 50);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it. This will really help me with future assignments as well.